# java: get fileobject attribute (mtime, atime)

Tags: java

I have a SftpFileObject - inherits FileObject (which I'm trying to download from a file). For this object I can see in a debugger its attrs (for example mtime, ctime, size etc)

How can I access them / get the values of the attrs (attribute)?

I'm getting empty list if I try following:

```
String [] attributes = myFileObject.getContent().getAttributeNames();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileObject.html), you can get mtime from the doGetLastModifiedTime member function and size from the doGetContentSize member function.